# How to pass a 2D array as a parameter in C?

Tags: c, arrays

The section of function is never entered in the following code
please help me out!

```
#include<stdio.h>
int findMax(int *a[], int m, int n)//this function is not entering
{
    int i,j,k=0;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        if(k<a[i][j])
           k=a[i][j];
    printf("hi");//this hi is also not printing
                 //this hi is just for testing
    return k;
}
```

//This function correct it if possible

```
int main()
{
   int m,n,a[50][50],i,j,k=0;
   printf("Enter the number of rows in the matrix\n");
   scanf("%d",&m);
   printf("Enter the number of columns in the matrix\n"); 
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("Enter the elements in the matrix\n");
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
      scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    } 
  printf("The matrix is");
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
     printf("\n");
     for(j=0;j<n;j++)
       printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
  }
  k=findMax((int **)a,m,n);//statements after this is never running but no
                           //compilation errors
  printf("\nThe maximum element in the matrix is %d",k);
  return 0;
}
```

please help me out!!
Thanks to you in advance!!

Comment: What if i put `m` and `n` as 201 and 403?

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see what happens?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i already have executed and it shows so like compile time error

Comment: @SouravGhosh hy it was juz asked for 15*15 y do u go there? i just need a solution for this!

Comment: `hy it was juz asked for 15*15 y do u go there? i just need a solution for this! `... I just wanted to give some free advice to save your program for erroneous inputs. if you're fine with a _near-broken_ code, and `just need a solution for this`, then God help you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
int findMax(int *a[], int m, int n)
```

`int *a[]` is an array of pointers to `int`, you want a pointer to an array of 50 `int`'s:

```
int findMax(int (*a)[50], int m, int n)
```

or

```
int findMax(int a[][50], int m, int n)
```

You don't need the cast, call it using:

```
k = findMax(a, m, n);
```

Or you can use a flat array, an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int *arr, int rows, int cols)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i * cols + j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 3

int main(void)
{
    int arr[ROWS * COLS];
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            arr[i * COLS + j] = i * COLS + j;
    }
    foo(arr, ROWS, COLS);
    return 0;
}
```

If you dont know the sizes of the 2d array beforehand you can use `malloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(int *arr, int rows, int cols)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i * cols + j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, rows, cols;
    int *arr;

    printf("Num of rows:");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Num of cols:");
    scanf("%d", &cols);
    arr = malloc(rows * cols);
    if (arr == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            arr[i * cols + j] = i * cols + j;
    }
    foo(arr, rows, cols);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I don't get you, where is the problem with `a[50][50]`?

Comment: m and n is not merely to have been using that part.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I still don't get you

Comment: Why are you using `foo(3, 2, a);` and `bar(a, 3, 2);`, dimensions are `50*50`

Comment: `foo` is intended to embody your example(i said last one). It does not work as expected. you remember that `n` and `m` are input by user, might not `50`.

Comment: should be `foo(arr, m, n);` : m and n are inputs by user.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, are you sure?, `i = ROWS` and `j = COLS` after the for loop.

Comment: `foo(arr, i, j);` meant `foo(arr, ROWS, COLS);` , `foo(arr, 3, 3);` doesn't make sense. OP is intended to use a part of a two-dimensional array, not all.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, both are the same, I want to pass `ROWS` and `COLS`, where do you see the problem passing `i` and `j`?, is just an example flatting a 2d array :)

Comment: Is mean to create an array of size that is required? Although prepared in advance, rather than using a portion.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing here: `int findMax(int *a[], int m, int n)` is trying to point at int 50 times, but you want to point at a variabile type int 50 times. therefor you want to decleare the pointer before you decleare the array.

use therefor:

```
int findMax(int (*a)[], int m, int n)
```

this should work now without the casting

just turn it into:

```
k=findmax(a,m,n);
```

[here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm) is a simple tutorial on the subject.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i don't get what you mean?? can you explain please?

Comment: `int (*a)[]` is invalid. cannot compile.

Comment: [C99](http://ideone.com/y0B6Sy) and  [g++ 4.9.2](http://ideone.com/nP8kBD) both cannot be compile.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY wierd, but lets hope it compiles for Arun

Comment: no, the size of array of a two-dimensional  is not  determine  array as error message is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MATRIX_SIZE 50

int findMax(int a[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE], int m, int n){
    //Valid any of the following is
    //int a[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE]
    //int a[][MATRIX_SIZE]
    //int (*a)[MATRIX_SIZE]
    int i, j, k=INT_MIN;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            if(k<a[i][j])
                k=a[i][j];
    return k;
}

int main(void){
    int m, n, a[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE], i, j, k=0;

    printf("Enter the number of rows(<=50) in the matrix\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Enter the number of columns(<=50) in the matrix\n"); 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(m < 1 || n < 1 || m > 50 || n > 50){
        printf("invalid input!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Enter the elements in the matrix\n");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);

    printf("The matrix is");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
    }
    k=findMax(a, m, n);
    printf("\nThe maximum element in the matrix is %d\n", k);

    return 0;
}
```